# Variance of an estimator of a certain Markov process with reversibility property

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

We have a discrete-time Markov chain $X_0, X_1, ...$

And $p(X_0=x)=q(x), p(X_{i+1}=y|X_i=x)=k(x,y),i\in \mathbb N$

$k(x,y)$ has property that $f(x)k(x,y)=f(y)k(y,x)$, where f(x) is some probability density function.

It can be shown that

$E(\frac{f(X_0)}{q(X_0)}h(X_i))=$

$\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{} \frac{f(X_0)}{q(X_0)}h(X_i)p(X_0,...,X_i) \,dX_0...dX_i=$

$\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{} \frac{f(X_0)}{q(X_0)}h(X_i)q(X_0)k(X_0,X_1)...k(X_{i-1},X_i) \,dX_0...dX_i=$

$\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{} h(X_i)f(X_0)k(X_0,X_1)...k(X_{i-1},X_i) \,dX_0...dX_i=$

$\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{} h(X_i)f(X_1)k(X_1,X_0)...k(X_{i-1},X_i) \,dX_0...dX_i=$

$\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{} h(X_i)f(X_i)k(X_1,X_0)...k(X_i,X_{i-1}) \,dX_0...dX_i=$

$\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{} h(X_i)f(X_i)k(X_2,X_1)...k(X_i,X_{i-1}) \,dX_1...dX_i=$

$\int_{}^{} h(X_i)f(X_i) \,dX_i$

So we have that $E(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{f(X_0)}{q(X_0)}h(X_i))=\int_{}^{} h(X_0)f(X_0) \,dX_0$

My question is that what's the variance of the above estimator $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{f(X_0)}{q(X_0)}h(X_i)$?

Comment: $f(x)k(x,y)=f(y)k(y,x)$ is called "reversibility property".

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to be a good descriptor of the content of your question. Do you agree ?

Comment: @JeanMarie : Yes, thank you!

Comment: $h$ can be any function ?

Comment: @JeanMarie : Yes, make any assumptions you want to.